# ui.bootstrap.modal template element not selectable?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using **ui.bootstrap.modal** with a templateUrl.  Within my template HTML, I have a "div" element that serves as a container for a third-party component (SlickGrid). When initializing my third-party component, I specify it's containing element using a jQuery selector expression.  However, the selector can't seem to *find* my container element when executed from either within the modal's controller or within my 'opened' promise logic as resolved by modal. I believe the problem is that my dialog HTML hasn't yet been added to the DOM and thus isn't visible to the controller or 'opened' promise.  I should add that the dialog itself renders just fine; it's just that I can't reference its container element from ... any context?  Perhaps modal doesn't support this use-case? Any thoughts/suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks, Garry

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken your question.
You can use bs.modal.shown in your modal shown event

`$(your-modal).on("bs.modal.shown",function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while using **bootstrap-table** inside a **ui.boostrap.modal** - when I initialize my modal, the selector wasn't able to find the `<table>` element & so couldn't be initialized itself.

The answer was to use the `rendered` promise, rather than `opened`. `rendered` resolves once the template has been added to the DOM, allowing you to select elements defined in the template as you would normally.

Below is a sample of how my implementation was done:

**My View**

```
<div ng-controller="MyAngularController" ng-init="init()">
    <!-- The actual page content goes here - irrelevant to the example -->

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myngtemplate.html">
        <table id="mygrid">
            <!-- My bootstrap-table column definitions here -->
        </tabie>
    </script>
</div>
```

**My JavaScript**

```
// the below was implemented in my page's AngularJS controller,
// left out the controller implementation to make the example more consise

var modal = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    size: 'lg',
    templateUrl: 'myngtemplate.html'
});

modal.rendered.then(function () {
    // $('#mygrid') could not find the table element before this
    $('#mygrid').bootstrapTable({
        data: getModalData()
    });
});
```